# Remove php extension and allow files to be loaded without extension using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to forcefully remove the php extension from the URL and also allow files to be loaded without the extension.

Right now, I'm using this to remove the php extension

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.+)\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

And this to allow files to be loaded without an extension

```
Options +Followsymlinks
Rewriteengine On
Rewritebase /
Rewritecond %{Request_Filename} !-f
Rewritecond %{Request_Filename} !-d
Rewritecond %{Request_Filename}.Php -f
Rewriterule ^(.+)$ /$1.Php [L,Qsa]
```

This works, but it seems like an overkill. I was thinking about using mutiviews to allow files to be loaded without an extension, but decided against it because of the security vulnerability.

Is there a better way to do these two things?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a HTTP router in PHP. Example will route all requests to index.php else the file exists.

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php
switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
     case '/url1':
          // handle url1
     case '/url2':
          // handle url2
     default:
          // 404 page
}
```

If you want to go simpler, look into [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com) or [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing)

To cover routing URL to PHP file could be something like this.

.htaccess

```
 Rewrite On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it through just htaccess?

Comment: I added another htaccess that allow http://example.com/test to be routed to /test.php but it will route any request that isn't a file on the server.

Comment: I had the same code in my question. But what I wanted to know was if I could forcibly remove the extension and display the file without an extension in a better way

Comment: I would look more into slim. It will take any URL and allow you to process the request based on the URL that comes in.  The last example I have up there does remove the PHP extension.